# Is cascade triggered by putting a creature into play?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Wild Pair](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=122468) is on the field when I cast a 5/5, and I use Wild Pair to put [Enlisted Wurm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=185047) into play, does Enlisted Wurm's cascade trigger?

> Wild Pair: Whenever a creature enters the battlefield, if you cast it from your hand, you may search your library for a creature card with the same total power and toughness and put it onto the battlefield. If you do, shuffle your library.
>
> Enlisted Wurm: Cascade (When you cast this spell, exile cards from the top of your library until you exile a nonland card that costs less. You may cast it without paying its mana cost. Put the exiled cards on the bottom of your library in a random order.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### No.  Cascade triggers when the spell with Cascade is cast.

Casting a spell is different from putting a permanent into play.  Casting a permanent spell puts that spell on the stack.  When a permanent spell resolves, that permanent enters play.  There are other ways of putting a permanent directly into play (like Wild Pair) that do not involve casting a spell.

Answer (score 3):

**Cascade does not trigger.**

Searching the library and putting the card into play does not equal to casting a spell.

In Order to get the behaviour you're asking of, Wild Pairs triggered ability would have to be worded differently, e.g.:

Wild Pair: Whenever a creature enters the battlefield, if you cast it from your hand, you may search your library for a creature card with the same total power and toughness. *You may cast it without paying its mana cost*. If you do, shuffle your library.